# How can I filter objects based on date property

Tags: angular

I have the following json:

```
[
  {
    "id": "58b1f024-f9dc-44d3-b07e-9672b5815563",
    "userId": "0fdba3ec-90c2-41d7-9912-904f9d0b415d",
    "appointment_date": "Tue Oct 20 2020",
    "appointment_hour": "10:00 - 11:00",
    "created_at": "2020-10-20T21:03:08.285Z",
    "updated_at": "2020-10-20T21:03:08.285Z"
  },
  {
    "id": "05591548-dbbe-49dc-a852-e887487bf2a6",
    "userId": "ea97c2db-bdb3-4323-a070-91d751aa09b7",
    "appointment_date": "Fri Oct 21 2020",
    "appointment_hour": "14:00 - 15:00",
    "created_at": "2020-10-20T22:08:16.307Z",
    "updated_at": "2020-10-20T22:08:16.307Z"
  },
  {
    "id": "5e57942d-33f6-40a8-aae7-bb84fd4c156e",
    "userId": "ea97c2db-bdb3-4323-a070-91d751aa09b7",
    "appointment_date": "Tue Oct 27 2020",
    "appointment_hour": "20:00 - 21:00",
    "created_at": "2020-10-20T22:08:17.745Z",
    "updated_at": "2020-10-20T22:08:17.745Z"
  },
  {
    "id": "dfc2a605-4e34-4110-8f91-64e618f7c846",
    "userId": "0fdba3ec-90c2-41d7-9912-904f9d0b415d",
    "appointment_date": "Tue Oct 27 2020",
    "appointment_hour": "13:00 - 14:00",
    "created_at": "2020-10-20T22:09:33.587Z",
    "updated_at": "2020-10-20T22:09:33.587Z"
  }
]
```

I need to show this data on the page but to be dynamicly calculated.
For example if there is passed appointment ( Date: Tue Oct 20 2020 ) then i should have one row with PASSED APPPOINTMENT HEADER and the filtered objects inside that row with passed dates

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" *ngFor='let appointment of json'>
    <h1>
      Passed appointment
    </h1>
    
    <div>
      {{ appointment.appointment_date}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If it is today's date then the objects from today in other row. And if it appointment_date is for example the next week ( Tue Oct 27 2020: from the example ) or next month then should be showed in other row with NEXT WEEK OR NEXT MONTH. How can all of this be achived dinamicly ?

Comment: You can implement a custom pipe for this, like this example in official docs -> https://angular.io/guide/pipes#detecting-pure-changes-to-primitives-and-object-references

Comment: Hello Berk.On this example they are only getting by simple filter- hero => hero.canFly. I need some filter on date and specific to my requirements needs to be splitted into different rows.